# Tab application. Need guidance

Tags: javascript

So,I have to make a tab application for products. Basically,my ideea,is like this:If you're on product page and it finds a certain tag(I give options like h1 h2 h3 ) it makes the chosen tag as the title and the content as a tab. Any ideea how can I know how much content to get ?

Comment: You need to give us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your tries so we can help you.

Comment: Provide images, code, concepts, visual information that will help us help you. Vouch to @SebastianSpeitel for being blatantly obvious about it.